# Preserving form fields(input/select/checkbox) in an .hta file. So original user and/or another user can open and see the filled out information

Tags: javascript, html, hta

I need some help with an `.hta` file I am creating for my work. I am good with HTML but JavaScript is another realm for me. I've always been able to look at examples and piece together different examples but what I'm trying to accomplish is beyond my expertise.

Right now I have successfully created an `.hta` that allows a user to select a checkbox telling the code to select the school, then select an option in a drop-down and add any other information in a text field. When the user clicks save changes, it outputs an `.xml` file.

My issue is when a user closes the `.hta` file, all of the fields and selections and check boxes are blank when re-opened. I have scoured code examples everywhere trying to find a way to preserve the data. I won't go into detail but html5 localstorage won't work and JavaScript cookies wont work because those are restricted to a local user.

I want to preserve all data that has been entered so any user(from any workstation) can open the `.hta` and not have to refill out all the fields and selections.

The three solutions I have found:

1. An external serialized JSON file saved locally, then called when the `.hta` is opened.
2. Using this guys JavaScript: [hta-localstorage](https://github.com/insin/hta-localstorage)
3. Read the information from the created `.xml` file.

Unfortunately, I lack the knowledge on how to implement any of those options. If I give an example of my existing code, could someone help me implement one of the previous mentioned methods? Or maybe someone has an easier alternative?

Script:

```
<script>
function WriteToFile()
{
  try 
  {
    var WshNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
    var userName = WshNetwork.UserName;
    var fso, s;
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    s = fso.CreateTextFile("xml_output/sc_output.xml", true);

    var B_B_P=document.getElementById("A_Bright_Beginning_Preschool").checked;
    var B_B_P_selected=document.getElementById("A_Bright_Beginning_PreschoolSelected").value;   
    var B_B_P_other=document.getElementById("A_Bright_Beginning_PreschoolOther").value;

    var A_S_Cath_S=document.getElementById("All_Saints_Catholic_School").checked;
    var A_S_Cath_S_selected=document.getElementById("All_Saints_Catholic_SchoolSelected").value;    
    var A_S_Cath_S_other=document.getElementById("All_Saints_Catholic_SchoolOther").value;

s.writeline("\<\?xml version\=\"1\.0\" encoding\=\"UTF\-8\" standalone\=\"yes\"\?\>");
s.writeline("\<School\_data xmlns\:xsi\=\"http\:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2001\/XMLSchema\-instance\"\>");

if (B_B_P==false)
        {
        s.writeline("");
        }
        else
            {
            s.writeline("   \<record\>");
            s.writeline("       \<School\_Name\>A Bright Beginning Preschool\<\/School\_Name\>");
            s.writeline("       \<School\_Seq\>001\<\/School\_Seq\>");
            s.writeline("       \<Delay\>" + B_B_P_selected + "\<\/Delay\>");
            s.writeline("       \<Other\>" + B_B_P_other + "\<\/Other\>");
            s.writeline("   \<\/record\>");
            }
if (A_S_Cath_S==false)
        {
        s.writeline("");
        }
        else
            {
            s.writeline("   \<record\>");
            s.writeline("       \<School\_Name\>All Saints Catholic School\<\/School\_Name\>");
            s.writeline("       \<School\_Seq\>002\<\/School\_Seq\>");
            s.writeline("       \<Delay\>" + A_S_Cath_S_selected + "\<\/Delay\>");
            s.writeline("       \<Other\>" + A_S_Cath_S_other + "\<\/Other\>");
            s.writeline("   \<\/record\>");
            }
            s.writeline("\<\/School\_data\>");
    s.Close();
  } 
  catch(err)
  {
   var strErr = 'Error:';
   strErr += '\nNumber:' + err.number;
   strErr += '\nDescription:' + err.description;
   document.write(strErr);
  }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<h1>School Closures</h1>
<br />
<form>
<table width="900" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox" name="A_Bright_Beginning_Preschool" id="A_Bright_Beginning_Preschool" /></td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">A Bright Beginning Preschool</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><select name="A_Bright_Beginning_PreschoolSelected" id="A_Bright_Beginning_PreschoolSelected">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="1 Hour Late">1 Hour Late</option>
        <option value="2 Hours Late">2 Hours Late</option>
        <option value="3 Hours Late">3 Hours Late</option>
        <option value="4 Hours Late">4 Hours Late</option>
        <option value="No School">No School</option>
    </select></td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="A_Bright_Beginning_PreschoolOther" type="text" id="A_Bright_Beginning_PreschoolOther" size="80" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox" name="All_Saints_Catholic_School" id="All_Saints_Catholic_School" /></td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">All Saints Catholic School</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><select name="All_Saints_Catholic_SchoolSelected" id="All_Saints_Catholic_SchoolSelected">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="1 Hour Late">1 Hour Late</option>
        <option value="2 Hours Late">2 Hours Late</option>
        <option value="3 Hours Late">3 Hours Late</option>
        <option value="4 Hours Late">4 Hours Late</option>
        <option value="No School">No School</option>
    </select></td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="All_Saints_Catholic_SchoolOther" type="text" id="All_Saints_Catholic_SchoolOther" size="80" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating the XML file every time in your WriteToFile code?

s = fso.CreateTextFile("xml_output/sc_output.xml", true);

That'll overwrite the previously created XML file when called. You`ll need some logic in your code to check if the XML file exists, and if so, read the relevant content and populate your HTML fields with it.

In pseudo(-ish)-code terms:

```
if not fso.fileExists("output.xml") then
Set outFILE = fso.createTextFile("output.xml")
else
Set inFILE = fso.openTextFile("output.xml"), 1) ' ForReading
rawXML = inFILE.ReadAll
inFILE.Close
end if
```

.. there are some XML handling tools in vbscript (create an XML object and read it in, or process specific elements etc). But you`ll need to sort the file creation issue first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am overwriting the xml each time someone clicks save changes by design. It's a school closure form so each time they open it, it needs to either read the xml file of preserve the form data another way.

Comment: How would I implement the code above into my existing code? An example of it and I can build from there.